# Eigenvalue Decomposition That Does Not Result in Original Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have an upper triangular $m \times m$ matrix with **1's** on the main diagonal and **2's** on the first superdiagonal and **0's** elsewhere. It is fairly easy to see that this is a full rank matrix with eigenvalues of all **1's**.

Now the eigenvalue decomposition is supposed to give me a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and a matrix of eigenvectors such that

$$ A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} $$

where the columns of Q are the eigenvectors. Then the inverse of $A$ is

$$ A^{-1} = Q \Lambda^{-1} Q^{-1} = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} = A $$

However, this is not true for the matrix **A** that I described. So now my question is, why does the eigenvalue decomposition not work for this matrix? If I am not making a mistake somewhere, how then can I invert the matrix **A** without resorting to something like Gauss Elimination or the sort?

I tried using Matlab's *eig* function and found that the matrix **Q** returned does not satisfy $A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$ which evaluates to the identity matrix. I try to to rely much on a numerical implementation that involves the inverse of a matrix because I know inverting matrices numerically can be ill-conditioned and lead to severed numerical issues. However, I would expect that an eigenvalue decomposition would yield reasonable results when the eigenvalues are not too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all matrices are diagonalizable. Yours in particular is not. Suppose it were, so that you can write $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ with $\Lambda$ diagonal. The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal elements, so we have $\Lambda=I$, but then $Q\Lambda Q^{-1} = QQ^{-1} = I \ne A$.

Why does this go wrong? In the above diagonalization the columns of $Q$ are linearly-independent eigenvectors of $A$. Unfortunately, for your matrix the only eigenvectors are multiples of the standard basis vector $(1,0,0,\dots,0)^T$. Except in the trivial case of $m=1$ there aren’t enough of them to form the diagonalizing matrix $Q$. What you will need to do instead if you want to proceed along these lines is find the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  Your $A$ is an example of a matrix which is not diagonalizable for $m>1$. In that case, there is no such decomposition.  There are a number of characterizations of diagonalizability, and the Wikipedia page is pretty good https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable

I don't know what Matlab is returning, even after reading https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html  It looks like they're returning a $Q$ and $D$ such that $AQ=QD$, but $Q$ won't be invertible if $A$ is not diagonalizable.